# installing and configuring symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I created my new project in Symfony 3.4.* and but not using the build-in webserver. I am using a shared Hosting with runs on Nginx. I change the root .../public_html to root .../public_html/web which includes the app.php etc. I am now able to visit domain/app.php which shows that Symfony is running. But if i change the DefaultController route from "/" to "/home" its not working for some reason. It says "File not found."

Whats going wrong exactly? I did try to create an symbolic link from /web to ../public_html but this did not work.

Please assist.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this, from the Nginx site.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/symfony/

You shoud modify that according to your needs.

Comment: Link only answers (especially non-applicable ones) tend to get down voted.